# "NSInternalInconsistencyException" Entities for a configuration must already be in the model

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectmodel, nsincrementalstore

I am trying to add a new entity in **NSManagedObjectModel** in my **NSIncrementalStore Subclass**. I am doing this in loadMetadata method but it keeps throwing this exception on the last line. See Code Below

**"NSInternalInconsistencyException" Entities for a configuration must already be in the model**

**Code**

```
var model:AnyObject=(self.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel.copy())!
var newEntity=NSEntityDescription()
newEntity.name="newEntity"
newEntity.managedObjectClassName="newEntity"

var entities=model.entitiesForConfiguration(self.configurationName)
entities?.append(newEntity)

model.setEntities(entities!, forConfiguration: self.configurationName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a model after it has been added to a persistent store coordinator.  The only time you can manipulate the model is just after initialization and before applying it to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

Comment: The code above is before I add it to NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. It still throws this exception. I am actually trying to make a copy of the model and  add it to NSIncrementalStore's private instance of NSPersistentStoreCoordinator ! It works when I add any new attributes to entities but not when I try to add a new entity !

Comment: In the code above you are retrieving the model from the PSC so that indicates to me that the model has already been added to the PSC and therefore has already been "touched".

Comment: Can you isolate this in a test case that I can play with?

Comment: I am making a mutable copy of the "touched" model !

Comment: @NofelMahmood I believe you have found a bug, did you report this through radar?

Comment: I do not see this as a bug in Core Data. You cannot take an immutable model and make it mutable. This is not like other muta blue objects on Cocoa. If anything, your ability to add properties is a bug. Would still like to see a test case so that we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: anyone knows how to add entities in model i am trying but i getting error for configuration of model

Comment: @chetanpanchal It is inappropriate to post a question in comments.  Please open your own question directly.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is unclear about this, but before calling `setEntities:forConfiguration:` the entities being set must already exist in the managed object model's `entities` array. This is because this method actually assigns *existing* entities in the model to a particular configuration.

The solution here is to make a mutable copy of the `entities` array, add your entities to it if they do not exist, and then set the managed object model's entities array to an immutable copy of the modified array.
After that point you can invoke `setEntities:forConfiguration:`.

It would be worth filing a radar bug report on this behavior.